# json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field .result.case_report of type main.CaseReport

Tags: json, go, struct, type-conversion, isnullorempty

I need to unmarshal an API response that not always includes values for some of the structs defined inside the main struct.  The main struct looks like this:

```
type CaseResponse struct {
    Result struct {
        GroupList               string `json:"group_list"`
        UCopiedFrom             string `json:"u_copied_from"`
        UOfferVariant           string `json:"u_offer_variant"`
        SyncDriver              string `json:"sync_driver"`
        PrimaryContact          *PrimaryContact `json:"primary_contact,omitempty"`
        Entitlement             string          `json:"entitlement"`
        CaseReport              *CaseReport     `json:"case_report,omitempty"`
        ResolvedAt              string          `json:"resolved_at"`
    } `json:"result"`
}
```

The internal structs for above json are defined as:

```
type PrimaryContact struct {
    Link  string `json:"link,omitempty"`
    Value string `json:"value,omitempty"`
}
type CaseReport struct {
    Link  string `json:"link,omitempty"`
    Value string `json:"value,omitempty"`
}
```

It is common for PrimaryContact and CaseReport to return empty, and when they do, Go throws error:  json cannot unmarshal string into Go struct .result.case_report of type main.CaseReport

I looked for possible fixes. First I added the ",omitempty" to the values for the internal structs, but didn't fix the problem.  Then added the pointers for PrimaryContact and CaseReport as found in some other postings, but I'm still hitting the same error when the response comes back with those fields with no data such as:

```
{
  "result": {
    "group_list": "",
    "u_copied_from": "",
    "u_offer_variant": "",
    "sync_driver": "false",
    "primary_contact":"",
    "entitlement": "",
    "case_report": "",
    "resolved_at": ""
}
```

but works fine when primary_contact and case_report values come back as:

```
{
  "result": {
    "group_list": "",
    "u_copied_from": "",
    "u_offer_variant": "",
    "sync_driver": "false",
    "primary_contact": {
      "link": "some link",
      "value": "1e717ed013897b00f2345aa12244b003"
    },
    "entitlement": "",
    "case_report": {
      "link": "some link",
      "value": "2b10fa5e1b1b19d45836ea89bd4bcb35"
    },
    "resolved_at": ""
}
```

How can the response be safely unmarshal when those fields have no value returned?

Comment: Your JSON is ugly. You thus need an ugly solution: Use `json.RawMessage` or `any` as the type of CaseReport. Then process the RawMessage in a second step or type switch on any. SO is full of this type of question. Best solution is to have the JSON fixed (by using e.g. null or omiting the field altogether.

Comment: `""` is NOT *"no value"*. "No value" in JSON is either `null` or the actual exclusion of the target property in the source. An empty string is a valid string value and string values should be unmarshaled into Go strings not structs. Plain Go structs or pointers to structs can be decoded only from JSON **objects**, not empty strings. `,omitempty` is a marshal thing, it has zero effect on unmarshaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the [unmarshaler interface](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) on `PrimaryContact` and `CaseReport`.  Do nothing when the value is the empty string.

```
func (pc *PrimaryContact) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    if string(p) == `""` {
        // empty string, do nothing
        return nil
    }
    // Prevent recursion to this method by declaring a new
    // type with same underlying type as PrimaryContact and
    // no methods. 
    type x PrimaryContact
    return json.Unmarshal(p, (*x)(pc))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/UHJobDw5RR2

> Go throws error ...

The encoding/json package function returned the error. Go does not have the throw feature.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).